# Recorre variable con un Store

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Estoy haciendo store procedure. Pero tengo una duda sobre la consulta que su resultados son dos valores. (@VarId)

Necesito pasarlo los dos valores la segundo consulta, para que me devuelva aquellos datos que no se encuentra en la tb_cambio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CambioSinAsignar
@IdProducto int

AS
BEGIN
    declare @varId int
    set  @varId= (SELECT IdCambio from tb_Producto_Cambio where IdProducto=@IdProducto)


    select distinct tb_Cambio.IdCambio, tb_Cambio.Nombre,tb_Cambio.Descripcion, 
    tb_Cambio.AproxHoras 
    from tb_Cambio
    right join 
    tb_Producto_Cambio on tb_Cambio.IdCambio=tb_Producto_Cambio.IdCambio
    where tb_Producto_Cambio.IdProducto<> @IdProducto and tb_Producto_Cambio.IdCambio<> 
    @varId
END
```

Comment: mira [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure) hacen la misma pregunta y tienes la solución con una respuesta amplia. Saludos!

Comment: existe alguna forma de realizar un for que permita recorrer la variable y asignarle valores al select?

Comment: En donde deseas agregarlo? Podrías editar la pregunta poniendo un ejemplo del parámetro y como debería quedar la consulta. De este modo va a ser mas claro para ayudarte.

Comment: Agregue más datos, espero que me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Leí varias veces tu pregunta y de verdad no me queda claro lo que quieres lograr. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), y luego editar esta con más información, ya que eso incrementará tus probabilidades de obtener ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

En una variable int no puedes guardar varios valores, necesitarías una variable table:

```
  declare @varId table (id int)
insert into @varId
SELECT IdCambio from tb_Producto_Cambio where IdProducto=@IdProducto


select distinct tb_Cambio.IdCambio, tb_Cambio.Nombre,tb_Cambio.Descripcion, 
tb_Cambio.AproxHoras 
from tb_Cambio
right join 
tb_Producto_Cambio on tb_Cambio.IdCambio=tb_Producto_Cambio.IdCambio
where tb_Producto_Cambio.IdProducto<> @IdProducto and 
tb_Producto_Cambio.IdCambio not in (select id from @varId)
```

Espero te sirva.